# How to use a selfie stick remote trigger with iPhone 3G?

Tags: iphone

I have an Apple IPhone 3G and Version 4.2.8 (8E401), and a generic selfie stick.  The selfie stick has a wire that plugs into the headphone jack on the phone, and when pressing the shutter release on the stick increases the volume?  It does not release the shutter to snap a photo.  Can you help with this issue?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The generic Selfie Stick button emulates the volume down button action on the iPhone. Initial iterations of iPhone(3G,4,4S) did not use the volume button as a shutter.

iPhone 5 and above introduced the volume down button as the "shutter key"

Alternatively, [Camera+][1] built the feature into their app back in 2011 for this purpose. Try the Selfie stick with the Camera+ app and it should work.

Incase it doesn't work, Open Safari and type `camplus://enablevolumesnap` into URL box and the feature will be enabled.

Comment: Wasn't Camera+ asked by Apple to remove this feature?

Comment: @patrix - Camera+ managed to include the feature hidden anyways.